# Call bot - how to?

Tags: android

We are looking to make an application in which a bot answers the call for us and says a predefined text like one sentence or two and the other person on their phone says/tells their work to the bot. Then after the call bot gives a speech to text.

**As per my research we can automatically pick call in Android Oreo using `android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS`**

But I don't know further steps. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Wow, so you are trying to replicate Google Duplex (https://www.androidauthority.com/what-is-google-duplex-869476/)? Good luck!!

Comment: Yes, kind of Google Call Screen / Google Duplex

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is almost impossible and very unreliable. Most phones don't have access to line audio since it is illegal to record calls in most countries.

This is the reason why most voice recorders can't record incoming audio in a call, at best they use the microphone to capture the audio coming from the speaker and some of them even require the phone to be rooted.

The permission `android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS` only allows you to automatically "Pick up" the phone, but does not give you access to the call audio.

Comment: So it means we can't create app like Google Call Screen / Google Duplex

Comment: On some phones it may work, but it will be very model specific. At least until that kind of feature starts showing up in newer phones. And even then, manufacturers may limit such functionality to root apps.

Comment: No problem. Sure I can be wrong, but this is the information I found while looking all around the Internet for a way to record calls on my Nexus 5x. Good luck!